# Handling signals from child process in Bash Scripts

Tags: c++, bash, signals

I am trying to trap a signal raised by a child process. However, my trap callback function is never called. I have the following test code

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(5));

    std::cout << ">>> Signal Sent!" << std::endl;
    raise(SIGUSR1);

    return 0;
}
```

And this bash script

```
set -bm
set -e 

KEEP_GOING=true

sigusr1()
{
    echo "SIGUSR1 Recieved"
    KEEP_GOING=false
}

trap sigusr1 SIGUSR1

./signalTest  &

while $KEEP_GOING ; do
    sleep 1s
    echo "Waiting for signal"
done
```

When I run it I get the following

```
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
>>> Signal Sent!
[1]+  User defined signal 1   ./signalTest
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
Waiting for signal
^C
```

From the output I see that the signal is in fact sent, and in some capacity received. However the callback function in my trap is not executed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're not sending a signal to the bash script.  `raise` sends the signal to the calling thread.

Comment: In other words, `signalTest` is sending a signal to itself and terminating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`raise`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/raise.3.html) sends the signal to the calling thread.

[`kill`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) sends a signal to the specified process or thread.

To send the signal to the parent process, instead of

```
raise(SIGUSR1);
```

do

```
#include <unistd.h>
// ...
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
```

Comment: @nicholishiell Read up http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: Okay so raise only signals the calling thread NOT the process? So my c++ code was signalling nothing. Where are kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1) sends the signal to the parent process (in this case the bash script). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @nicholishiell You are right. `raise` sends the signal to the calling thread/process. On Linux, the process id is the id of its first thread.